# How to parse a string with multiple underscores and dashes

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need some guidance and looking for a better way to parse strings.

**Example 1:**

String: `Automation_LOY_Loyalty_PC_CampaignName3-Abandoners-Email1_NoPromo_USA`

CSV: Automation, LOY, Loyalty, PC, CampaignName3, Abandoners, Email1, NoPromo, USA

**Example 2:**

String: `20200601_LOY_Functional_PC_CampaignName1_NoPromo_CAN`

CSV: 20200601, LOY, Functional, PC, CampaignName1,,, No Promo, CAN

As you can see, some strings don’t have all the fields, so some csv fields need to be left blank blank.

Right now I’m using this code below and it’s very messy. Is there a better way to handle it other than using CHARINDEX like this?

```sql
SELECT [EmailName]
      -- Deployment Type
      ,CASE LEFT([EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) - 1)
        WHEN 'Automation' THEN 'Automation' 
        ELSE 'AdHoc' END AS [Deployment]
      -- Type
      ,SUBSTRING([EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1) - 1) AS [Type]
      -- Customer_Type
      ,SUBSTRING([EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1) + 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName],CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1)) - CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) - 1) AS [Customer_Type]
      -- Campaign_Name
      ,CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) = 0 THEN SUBSTRING([EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1))) + 1, (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1)) + 1))) - (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1))) - 1)
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1))) + 1, ((CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) - (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1)))) - 1)
            ELSE NULL END AS [Campaign_Name]
      ,CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) = 0 THEN 1
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) > 0 THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING([EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) + 1), (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1) + 1)) + 1))) - (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])) - 1),'Email','')
            ELSE NULL END AS [Email_Num]
FROM TableName
```

Comment: I can see the format of your strings.  What do you want?  Sample data *and* desired results are helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry the csv desired result is there, but it was formatted on the same line so it was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is a little XML

Not clear if you want a comma delimited string or separate columns

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[SomeCol] varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Automation_LOY_Loyalty_PC_CampaignName3-Abandoners-Email1_NoPromo_USA')
,(2,'20200601_LOY_Functional_PC_CampaignName1_NoPromo_CAN')

Select A.ID 
      ,B.Pos1
      ,B.Pos2
      ,B.Pos3
      ,B.Pos4
      ,Pos5a = xmlData.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos5b = xmlData.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos5c = xmlData.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,B.Pos6
      ,B.Pos7
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'_','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
 Cross Apply ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(Pos5,'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) ) ) C(xmlData)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @user3276533 Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I will not fully answer the question but give you some clues anyway. In SQL Server you can use the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to split a string. But it accepts only one delimiter. Since it appears that you want to split on hyphen (`-`) and underscore (`_`) what you could do is:

- replace all occurrences of hyphen to underscore
- then split the string

Example:

```
declare @str varchar(500)
set @str = 'Automation_LOY_Loyalty_PC_CampaignName3-Abandoners-Email1_NoPromo_USA'
set @str = REPLACE(@str, '-', '_')

SELECT 
    value  
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT(@str,'_')
```

Result (9 rows):

```
Automation
LOY
Loyalty
PC
CampaignName3
Abandoners
Email1
NoPromo
USA
```

The problem is with the second string: `20200601_LOY_Functional_PC_CampaignName1_NoPromo_CAN`.

Result (7 rows):

```
20200601
LOY
Functional
PC
CampaignName1
NoPromo
CAN
```

There is no easy way to tell which fields are missing. If there was one 'placeholder' underscore per blank field we could count them but that is not the case here. Maybe you can devise a rule. But I am not sure SQL is the answer. Perhaps you should try a scripting language like Powershell to split the strings, look at the patterns and figure out which fields are present/missing.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a way to parse names in columns, not in rows.

Comment: This is a start. You can convert the rows back to columns (pivot or otherwise). Or in fact you could use `replace` twice to convert the hyphens and underscores to commas. But that does not solve the bigger issue: missing fields. I don't how to determine that.

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that string_split() does NOT guarantee the sequence.

Comment: Then drop the idea. Instead, you can just: `set @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, '-', '_'), '_', ',')` and you have a CSV string. Simply replacing every hyphen or underscore to a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I found STRING_SPLIT and PARSENAME but they weren't helpful. After some thought I precalculated the indexes in subquery.

```sql
SELECT
    x.[EmailName]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(x.[EmailName], Underscore_One - 1) = 'Automation' THEN 'Automation'
        WHEN LEFT(x.[EmailName], Underscore_One - 1) LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]' THEN 'Adhoc'
        ELSE NULL END AS [Deployment]
    ,SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName],Underscore_One + 1, Underscore_Two - Underscore_One - 1) AS [BU]
    ,SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName],Underscore_Two + 1, Underscore_Three - Underscore_Two - 1) AS [Type]
    ,SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName],Underscore_Three + 1, Underscore_Four - Underscore_Three - 1)  AS [Customer_Type]
    ,CASE WHEN x.Dash_Nums = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName],Underscore_Four + 1, Underscore_Five - Underscore_Four - 1) 
        WHEN x.Dash_Nums > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName], Underscore_Four + 1, Dash_One - Underscore_Four - 1) 
        ELSE NULL END AS [Campaign_Name]
    ,CASE WHEN x.Dash_Nums = 1 AND SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName], Dash_One + 1, Underscore_Five - Dash_One - 1) LIKE 'Email[0-9]%' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName], Dash_One + 1, Underscore_Five - Dash_One - 1),'Email','')
        WHEN x.Dash_Nums = 2 THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName], Dash_Two + 1, Underscore_Five - Dash_Two - 1),'Email','')
        ELSE NULL END AS [Email_Num]
    ,CASE WHEN x.Dash_Nums = 2 THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName], Dash_One + 1, Dash_Two - Dash_One - 1),'Email','')
        ELSE NULL END AS [Segment]
    ,CASE SUBSTRING(x.[EmailName],Underscore_Five + 1, Underscore_Six - Underscore_Five - 1)
        WHEN 'Promo' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN 'NoPromo' THEN 'N'
        ELSE NULL END AS [Promo_Flag]

FROM (SELECT [EmailName]
    ,LEN([EmailName]) - LEN(REPLACE([EmailName],'_','')) AS Underscore_Nums
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName]) AS Underscore_One
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) AS Underscore_Two
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1)) AS Underscore_Three
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1))) + 1)) AS Underscore_Four
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1))) + 1)) + 1)) AS Underscore_Five
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1))) + 1)) + 1)) + 1)) AS Underscore_Six
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName], ((CHARINDEX('_', [EmailName])) + 1)) + 1))) + 1)) + 1)) + 1)) + 1)) AS Underscore_Seven
      ,LEN([EmailName]) - LEN(REPLACE([EmailName],'-','')) AS Dash_Nums
      ,CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName]) AS Dash_One
      ,CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])  + 1)) AS Dash_Two
      ,CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName], (CHARINDEX('-', [EmailName])  + 1)) + 1)) AS Dash_Three
      -- Substring(Col, Start Index + 1, End Index - 1)
  FROM [minyoung].[dbo].[Consumer_Marketing_EmailName20200601]
    WHERE Campaign_Name = '') AS x
```